# Do a asynchronize trigger when textbox lose focus in MVC4?

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, jquery

In my ASP.NET MVC4 application, I've got a razor view where has a strongled-type. It's very simple.. the main thing here is this class has `IsCorrect()` method in it.

```
public class AbsoluteArithmetic
{
    public decimal? Result { get;set; }
    ....

    public override bool IsCorrect
    {
        get { return ... }
    }
}
```

Look below that I have a textBox where contains a property called Result. Also see the first code where starts the line `@if (@Model.IsCorrect()) {`, at the beginning I update a image through this method.

So, I would like to update again or fire a trigger to update the image when the textbox loses the focus. I just supposed that I need to use AJAX and JQuery, but I don't have idea what should I have to do.

```
@model Contoso.MvcApplication.Models.Exercises.AbsoluteArithmetic

<div>
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
    @***** when the textbox loses the focus, update the following code*****@
    @if (@Model.IsCorrect()) {
    <img src="correct.png" />
    }
    else {
    <img src="error.png" />
    }
    @**********************************************************************@

    <span style="padding:3px; font-size:18px;">@Model.Number1</span>
    <span style="padding:5px; font-size:18px;">+</span>
    <span style="padding:5px; font-size:18px;">@Model.Number2</span>
    <span style="padding:5px; font-size:18px;">=</span>

    <span style="font-size:18px">@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Result, new { style = "width:60px; font-size:18px;" })</span>
}
</div>
```

Comment: If all you're doing is addition is it really necessary to do it on the server side? JS can handle addition on its own quite well.

Comment: Well, this is just an example using adition. Is it possible to fire the method Correct using JS?

Comment: what data needs to be sent from page? Easy to tie AJAX to `blur()` of field

Comment: Yes, I was reading about blur event. Could you show an example doing that in AJAX? I don't know how to start

Comment: @charlietfl data? Is there a way to send the model as data?

Comment: you asked for a trigger in the page to send AJAX.... assumed you want to do calcs at server. If not...have no idea whatsoever what you are trying to do

Comment: Sorry I just supposed to use AJAX technology for this implementation. Which I'm trying to do is, when the textbox (at the bottom) loses the focus, asign its value to model.Result and run again the code which is between @************@